# Where to find Azure Sign-in activity report error codes list?

Tags: azure, authentication, error-handling

Can you please assist with finding the Azure Sign-in activity report error codes list?
I can't find this list on the portal/Google.

Comment: Please edit your question and include some of the error codes you're getting. Generally when you get an error, you get both the error code and error description.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to get the list prior to the errors I'm getting in order to write appropriate automation.

Comment: I believe this information is not available. Best I could find was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-sign-ins-error-codes.